# Element.animate() with variable as property to animate

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-animate

I want to use Element.animate() with the properties I want to animate as variables.But it seems that it doesn't work.

```
var pr="marginLeft"
document.getElementById("someId").animate([
  { pr:'0px' },
  { pr:'50px' },
],{
  duration:1000,
  fill:'forwards'
});
```

What can I do if I really need to use a variable instead of a property?

Comment: as i know that animate() method comes with jquery framwork..

Comment: I don't mean the Jquery animate method but the DOM Element.animate()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ES2015 computed property names.

```
let pr='marginLeft';

document.getElementById('someId').animate(
  [
    { [pr]: '0px' },
    { [pr]: '50px' },
  ],
  { duration:1000, fill:'forwards' }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object with the properties that you need, set the values using `obj[X] = Y`, and use this object as the parameter for your `animate` function:

```js
var pr="marginLeft";
var animationProperties = {
  duration: 1000,
  fill:'forwards'
}

// Here I added the `marginLeft` to the object:
animationProperties[pr] = '50px';

$('#someId').animate(animationProperties)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="someId">asd</div>
```